# Expanding a One-Class Support Vector Machine based on human input

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I have created a One-class SVM which I use to detect anomalies in vibration data for condition monitoring.

My idea is to use this as a basis for an expanded system. I want to cluster the detected anomalies and ask for user input regarding these cluster so that I may be able to not only detect anamolies, but also classify them.

Are there any algorithm which allows me to increase the number of classes in my SVM once a cluster has been detected with a fairly high level of certainty?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a good idea to use a `SVM` for this task? Consider another model such as a neural network (basic `MLP` architecture). Those are able to inherently perform multiclass classification.

What you could do, is to initially train it on your data using two output nodes, one for no detection and one for your class. Use a softmax function at your last layer and optimize the cross-entropy function. After the initial training and on user request, add another output node and fine-tune your model with every new provided sample. Your weights won't be lost and you just do some fine-tuning with every new class. Of course, this would take a lot of inputs to perfom well. But after some time, it should properly work. With an `SVM`, you actually would have to train a new `SVM` on your new class and implement some kind of voting scheme like `One-vs-All`. `SVMs` are inherently binary classifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Bastian. Seems to me like this could be a good option!

If i understand your proposal right;
I use the initial SVM classifications to construct a dataset with two classes (Faults and no faults)

Comment: Then use this to add more classes as new faults are introduced to the system. However i feel like I'm still missing one step here:  How do the system know when a new fault type is introduced?

In other words, I need to be able to differentiate between the first fault type that was detected and the new fault type.